# GPGS LoadScores() Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d, google-play-services

Использую [данный плагин](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) для **Unity3d**.

Возникают трудности при работе с функцией **LoadScores()**.

Есть две сцены на которых используются аналогичные методы вывода топа игроков. В первом случае все работает корректно, во втором содержится **InternalError** в свойстве **Status** возвращаемого объекта.

Пример рабочего (и вместе с тем нерабочего) кода:

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.LoadScores(
    _currentTopScoreType,
    LeaderboardStart.TopScores,
    10,
    LeaderboardCollection.Public,
    LeaderboardTimeSpan.AllTime,
    (data) =>
    {
        var userIDs = data.Scores.Select(score => score.userID).ToArray();
        Social.LoadUsers(userIDs, (users) =>
        {
          // Здесь отображаем очки
        });
    }
);
```

В нерабочем случае ответ с ошибкой приходит уже в **data.Status**. Единственной переменной, меняющейся в коде является **_currentTopScoreType**. Уже проверил, что в обоих случаях данный идентификатор присваивается корректно.

---

#### UPD

Инициализация **GPGS** производится в отдельном менеджере в загрузочной сцене (там же и аутентифицируется пользователь). Этот менеджер остается в иерархии объектов на протяжении всей работы приложения.

Вспомнив про **DRY** я перенес одинаковый код с разных сцен в метод данного менеджера:

```
public void LoadScores(string topScoreType, Action<LeaderboardScoreData, IUserProfile[]> callBackFunc)
{
    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.LoadScores(
        topScoreType,
        LeaderboardStart.TopScores,
        10,
        LeaderboardCollection.Public,
        LeaderboardTimeSpan.AllTime,
        (data) =>
        {
            var userIDs = data.Scores.Select(score => score.userID).ToArray();
            Social.LoadUsers(userIDs, (users) =>
            {
                callBackFunc(data, users);
            });
        }
    );
}
```

Сейчас с разных сцен (обозначим их **СЦЕНА1** и **СЦЕНА2**) вызывается данная функция. Тестирование выявило еще более интересную особенность:

- **СЦЕНА1**: загрузка топа игроков работает стабильно и независимо от производимых ранее действий.
- **СЦЕНА2**: **InternalError** возвращается при первой попытке загрузки топа, после чего работает стабильно при последующих вызовах.

На **СЦЕНА2** перед загрузкой топа у меня производится сохранение очков текущего пользователя. Думал, что связано с этим, но экспериментально не подтвердилось.

На горизонте уже маячит костыльное решение: грузить результаты на **СЦЕНА2** после первой неудачной попытки, но очень хотелось бы разобраться в причине происходящего.

Comment: Инициализация gps в каком месте/сцене происходит? Как эти сцены между собою связаны?

Comment: @Xumera_hZ обновил пост, спасибо за отклик.

Comment: А загрузка сцены2 идет после сцены1? Или без разницы в каком порядке загружаются сцены, на сцене2 будет internalError?(при перезагрузке сцены, тоже первая попытка internalError?) Вообще gps часто выдает ошибки, поэтому делали ручной timeout в 30-60сек, выводили сообщение пользователю типо ожидайте, и запускали загрузку до тех пор пока не будет success, timeout gps или свой ручной timeout. В итоге выводили ошибку и  предлагали пользователю, либо играть дальше, либо загрузить снова( try again)

Comment: @Xumera_hZ да, без разницы в каком порядке идёт загрузка. Ошибка возникает 1 раз на 2-ой сцене при работе приложения. То есть если возникла ошибка, а потом переходить между сценами, то ее уже не будет. При перезапуске приложения ситуация повторяется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено с помощью такого трюка:

```
public void LoadScores(
    string topScoreType,
    Action<LeaderboardScoreData, IUserProfile[]> callBackFunc,
    bool byself = false
)
{
    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.LoadScores(
        topScoreType,
        LeaderboardStart.TopScores,
        10,
        LeaderboardCollection.Public,
        LeaderboardTimeSpan.AllTime,
        (data) =>
        {
            if (data.Status == ResponseStatus.InternalError && !byself)
            {
                LoadScores(topScoreType, callBackFunc, true);
            }
            else
            {
                var userIDs = data.Scores.Select(score => score.userID).ToArray();
                Social.LoadUsers(userIDs, (users) =>
                {
                    callBackFunc(data, users);
                });
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Если результат загрузки неудачный и это первая попытка загрузки, то функция вызовет себя повторно. В причине происходящего разобраться не удалось, к сожалению, но думаю, что это может быть связано с тем, что плагин еще находится в разработке.